# How to group vector elements to bins without loop

Tags: arrays, loops, grouping

I need a way to find out which elements of a vector are within given bins (avoiding loops).

The vector is sorted and regularly spaced, e.g.:

```
vector = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Lower and upper boundaries of bins are known. Bins are of the same width and regularly spaced. They may overlap or have gaps inbetween, e.g.:

```
l_bnds = [.5, 2.8, 5.1, 7.4,  9.7]
u_bnds = [ 2, 4.3, 6.6, 8.9, 11.2]
```

What I want as output is an array with the indices of the elements in vector that are part of each bin (and -1 or so to fill up). n_rows: number of bins, n_cols: maximum number of elements in bins. In the above case:

```
 1     2
 3     4
 6    -1
 8    -1
-1    -1
```

It should be possible to choose if vector elements equalling boundaries are considered in or out (i.e., the interval may be defined as `(l,u)`, `(l,u]`, `[l,u)` or `[l,u])`. The output above assumes `[l,u]`.

It would be easy to loop over the bins and check where vector is between the respective boundaries. However, the vector and number of bins may be very large so I am looking for a way to avoid loops.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why no loops? Is this school work? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The algorithm shall be used to aggregate a large number of time series. They typically have 100,000+ values being aggregated to some 25,000 bins (e.g. 15 min to 60 min). I want to speed that up. I tried reforming the vector into a 2-dim array but don't know how to deal with different numbers of elements in each bin.

Comment: What language are you working in?